# Group by Weeks for successive years

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to aggregate data by weeks. My sample query looks like

```
SET DATEFIRST 1 

Select  ID, 
DATENAME(week, p.SellingDate) as SellingWeek, 
DATENAME(year, p.SellingDate) as SellingYear,
SUM(Quantity), 
SUM(Revenue)
 From dbo.Sales 
Where       
 p.SellingDate >=’2015-12-20’ and P.SellingDate < ’2016-02-27’
Group by ID,
DATENAME(week, p.SellingDate), 
  DATENAME(year, p.SellingDate)
```

When I try to do this, I am facing an issue:

The query returns correct data but the issue appears in the last week of 2015. It considers only the days (12/28 to 12/31) that are part of 2015 as the 53rd week and it considers the remaining part (01/01 to 01/03) as a new week of 2016. I only one row that has data for the whole week i.e. 12/28 to 01/03) but SQL Server returns 2 rows. Is there a workaround this?

Comment: That is because you are grouping by year so of course it is going to be a new row. You should look into DATEPART instead. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx

Comment: The reason I use grouping by year is because I need to generate the start date of the week later in the code. I need to aggregate by the week and then display the aggregated value with the start date . Can I generate the Start date of the week just by using DATEPART??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think you want to create a construct for grouping on week start and week end, then using that to group by for your aggregation clauses.

```
SET DATEFIRST 1

Select DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, p.SellingDate)-1), p.SellingDate) AS [WeekStart],
DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, p.SellingDate)), p.SellingDate) AS [WeekEnd], 
SUM(Quantity), 
SUM(Revenue)
From dbo.Sales 
Where       
p.SellingDate >= '2015-12-20' and P.SellingDate < '2016-02-27'
Group by ID,
DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, p.SellingDate)-1), p.SellingDate),
DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, p.SellingDate)), p.SellingDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by setting the week not based on the date of the sale but rather on the monday of week of the date of the sale.

```
select 
getdate() as today
datename(week, dateadd(dd,-1* (datepart(weekday, getdate())-1),getdate())) as monday,
```